# Change empty space to something java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java.
I'm reading in info from a textfile, which kind of looks like this:

```
asdasd  EE50 Psaefsdf
asrt    L38  sdfsdf
lookhere     sdfsdfs
sdfsdf  3PO  dsfsdf
more...
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to remove that empty space, where the numbers would normally be and change it to "x" or something. How would one do that?

```
Something like this?:

if(b.equals(" ")){
change to x or something? }
```

Associated code:

```
File filename = new File("a.file");
        Scanner Sc = new Scanner(filename);
        while (Sc.hasNextLine()) {              
                 String a = Sc.next();
                 String b = Sc.next();
                 String c = Sc.next();
```

After that they're added to objects, all.

Comment: if there are `\t`s in between columns maybe you could read line by line, split and look for empty spaces?

Answer (score 0):

```
String line ="....", newLine ="";
for(int i=0; i<line.Length; i++){
    if( !(line.charAt(i).equals(' ') || line.charAt(i).equals('\t')))
         newLine+= line.charAt(i);
    else
         newLine+= "x"; 
}
```

Or better use StringBuilder for eficiancy